# How to install all with aptitude

Tags: ubuntu, aptitude

How to install all packages whitch aptitude found?

For example:

```
sudo aptitude search eclipse
```

... found approximately 66 packages. How I can install all found packages without write separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `*` symbol as a wildcard.  I know it works when deleting files that may all be titled the same but have different dates attached to the file name.

In your case, you would type:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse*
```

This will install all packages that start with the string `eclipse`

versus:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

This will only install packages name "eclipse"

Comment: From the command-line, you should quote `"eclipse*"` if you intend passing it to apt-get as a pattern rather than expand it on the shell.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
sudo apt-get -d -u install $(apt-cache search -n eclipse | cut -f1 -d' ' | grep -vE 'redeclipse|^lib')
```

Note the `-d` for `--download-only`.  When you've made sure that it will install only what you want/need, remove the `-d` from the `apt-get` command.

`apt-cache search -n`'s output is far less "noisy" than `aptitude search`'s, so is easier to work with in a pipeline.

`redeclipse` is a game, not part of eclipse.  And you want libs to be pulled in as a dependancy so they're marked as auto-installed.  You can add any other packages you don't want installed to the `grep -vE` argument.